# How to refactor the error handling for a method with multiple steps?

Tags: java, android, refactoring

I have a method that comprises of 5 steps. Each step is a network call that may fail with a 403,404 etc. One of my coworker asked me to refactor the code because he thought there was a better way than checking the error after every network call. Can someone share some ideas on how to refactor this code? I am out of ideas myself.

Code (modified for simplicity):

```
public Void doInBackground() {
    // login step 1
    Response response = networkcall1.execute();

    if (shouldCancelLogin(response)) {
        clearloginToken();
        return null;
    }

    // login step 2
    Response response = networkcall2.execute();

    if (shouldCancelLogin(response)) {
        return null;
    }

    // login step 3
    // ...
    // login step 4
    // ...
    // login step 5
    // ...

    // login success!
}

private boolean shouldCancelLogin(Response response) {
    final HttpCode httpResponseCode = valueOf(response.code());

    // code for handling the errors
}
```

Comment: What are the `networkcall` variables? It seems like they've already been executed, no matter what. I'd recommend only making the next network call if the previous response is OK.

Comment: Instead of a helper method, the `response()` method can throw an exception and all of that can be placed in a try/catch block, and an exception at any step would process the same way.

Comment: Oops sorry that was supposed to be execute()

Comment: I don't really see a problem with this. The bigger issue is why you would have to make 5 requests to login, but that's not really up to the android application to handle.

Comment: Correct. It was not up to the app. The api requires 5 steps. The first step retrieves login info and the second step creates push-notification session etc.